# Unexplained Merge Conflict while merging from release to master [Git flow]

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-stash

I am following git flow for release management.

We use develop branch for development and integration. Once we are about to release we cut out release branch from develop. We keep fixing the issue to release in case any issue crop up and merge the same to develop.

After we are done completely. We merge release to master always. We never modify master directly ever by any means.
So Master is supposed to get only latest release to be done.

But still I always see merge conflict while raise PR from release to Master that is quite surprising. 
I know How to resolve that merge conflict. But question is 
**'Why merge from release to master show merge conflict at all'. We just double checked the master history to ensure nobody modified master.**

Is there any setting or anything which needs to ticked for the same in repository settings?

Comment: What merge conflict are you seeing ?

Comment: yes. In the PR i can see. it is mostyl project files and package files and even few code files too

Comment: Yes but what file(s) are in conflict ? Is it certain ones ?

Comment: .csproj and packages.config. It is c# project

Comment: If you really want to know the root cause of this merge conflict, you will have to dig into your git history. You will need to look at where `master` and your release branch diverge.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if I cut master from release, then in next release it should not show merge conflict?. In previous in order to rule out the diff I simple did it. I cut master from release            git checkout release/10.0        git checkout -b master git push

Comment: @Yogesh [Edit] your question and add those commands. There is definitely something strange going there.

Answer (score -1):

From comments:

> I cut master from release
>
> ```
> git checkout release/10.0
> git checkout -b master
> git push
> ```

---

Let's break down these commands one at a time:

```
 git checkout release/10.0
```

This checks out a branch named `release/10.0` **if that branch exists**. If the branch doesn't already exist, then git will throw an error:

> error: pathspec 'release/10.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.

```
git checkout -b master
```

This attempts to create a new branch named `master`. If the branch `master` already exists, then you should get another error:

> fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.

```
git push
```

This pushes the current branch. If you got the above error when trying to create the master branch, then you will push `release/10.0`.

With all that said, this series of commands seems strange because if you use Git Flow, you should already have a `master` branch. You should **not** create a new `master` each time you make a release. Instead, create a new release branch from master:

```
git checkout -b release/10.0 master
```

Then when the release is ready to deploy, you should merge your release branch into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge release/10.0
git push
```

If you do this every time and this is the only way to add commits to `master`, then your assumption is correct: you should never get any merge conflicts.

However, since you are seeing merge conflicts, other commits have been introduced to `master` that aren't on the release branch.

Comment: This was just to explain that no matter if I create master from release branch still but still subsequent release branch pull request it still shows merge conflict